# Actionscript3 parse XML node path with variables

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

Is it possible to use variables in XML node queries within Actionscript 3?

Given the following rss feed structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
  <item>
     <media:content url="http://www.example.com/test.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="683" width="1024" />
     <media:content url="http://www.example.com/test2.jpg" type="image/jpeg" height="683" width="1024" />
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The following code works as intended, displaying the url attribute value for the first content node within the media namespace:

```
var nsAttribute:String = 'media';
var nodeName:String = 'content';
var holder:String = 'item';
var imagePathAttribute = 'url';
// Pull the namespace attribute value from the xml declaration
var ns:String = rssXML.namespace(nsAttribute);
// Make a namespace instance based on the xpl namespace's URI
var imagePathNameSpace:Namespace = new Namespace( ns );

trace ( rssXML.channel.child(holder).imagePathNameSpace::content[0].@url );
```

Returns the expected result:

```
http://www.example.com/test.jpg
```

However, when I use the variables in the path node, I get an error.

```
trace ( rssXML.channel.child(holder).imagePathNameSpace::nodeName[0].@imagePathAttribute );
```

The error I receive is:

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

Probably because it can't find any value to index because the path returns an empty string.  If I remove the index section "[0]" from the path, it returns an empty string.

So how do I use the variables in the xml query?  The reason I'm trying to do this is to make the class I'm working on extensible enough that all we need to do is set the properties of the class, so it can work with different rss feed types and not have to hard-code for each specific feed.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is something like:

```
var node:XML = rssXML.channel.child(holder).imagePathNameSpace::content[0];
trace(node.attribute(imagePathAttribute));
```

You can manipulate directly attributes and node names using XML object methods. Using that, you can provide variables to functions.

[More informations are available here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#attribute%28%29)